# Vasicek model: joint simulation with discount factor

Tags: short-rate, vasicek

In Vasicek model, we have the following relation to get Discount factors given the value of short rate:
$$P(t\,,T)={{e}^{A(t,T)\,-\,B(t,T){{r}_{t}}\,}}$$

So, Discount factors are known as soon as we know the short rate. But then in some references like Glasserman (pg. 115) there is a whole subsection on "*Joint Simulation [of short rate] with the Discount Factor*" where he talks about simulating the pair $$({r}_{t},\int_{0}^t{r(u)}du)$$.

Piterbarg's book has something similar too. 
So my question is - why do we need to simulate Discount factor if we have an exact analytical result.

Comment: Read all of page 115 in Glasserman's book. Since the process X=(r,integral of r) is jointly Gaussian, it can be simulated with precision. We simulate X instead of simulating r and then estimating the integral of r with a sum.

Comment: @AXH thats exactly my confusion - why care about integral of r when we can calculate it's exact value analytically. Also, given we can exactly simulate r too, simulation precision cannot be the reason to simulate X. But since several references do it this way, there must be a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's been a long time this question has been asked, I'd like to propose an answer in case someone was looking for the same thing.

First, I think there's a confusion between $P(t,T)$ and $DF(t,T)$. The former is the $t-$price of a contract paying $1$ unit of currency at date $T$ while the later is the (stochastic) discount factor at $t$ for flows occuring at $T$. The two are linked through the relationship
$$ P(t,T)=\mathbb{E}^Q[DF(t,T) | \mathcal{F}_t]$$

If $r_t$ is the instantaneous short rate, then $DF(t,T)$ is given by
$$ DF(t,T)=e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds}$$
and is a random variable.

Now, the argument of Glasserman is about computing $\int_t^T r_s ds$. In theory, since one has $r_t$ up to maturity on a given path, this is just a matter of doing a Riemann sum. However, this may be very "noisy" because of discretization errors. It turns ou, as AXH mentionned, that $(r_t, \int_t^T r_s ds)$ are jointly gaussian and can be simulated precisely.

Comment: To complete this very good answer, as usually one needs to discount quantities, it's very useful to have the $\int_0^t r_s ds$ as well as $r_t$. For example, if you are computing the CVA of an interest rates swap, you need the values of $r_t$ to value it at $t > 0$, but you also need $\int_0^t r_s ds$ to discount the exposures to today to compute your CVA value.